# CSS WordPress Safari

Tags: css, wordpress, safari

I have a problem with the web browser Safari, I tested my website in Chrome, FireFox. The Safari version is correct too, however, when it's time to test it in a 1920x1080 or above it doesn't work properly (the footer section). [image] The theme I used is wp-simple and here's my CSS for this section

```
@media screen and (min-width : 1920px)
{
    .home .footer>div
    {
        width:100.7%;
        margin-left:-21%;
        margin-bottom:-9.6%;
    }

    p#copyright
    {
        margin-bottom:8%;
    }

    ::i-block-chrome, .home .footer > div
    {
        margin-left:-21% !important;
        margin-bottom:-8.9% !important;
    }
}
```

The link of my website : http://joelgobeil.ca/service/

Answer (score 0):

Hi I saw that the problem also occurs in Chrome so I tested the following In 
Chrome.

I Added the following CSS lines to the already existing ones.

```
div.container.footer {
    max-width: 100vw;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}

div.container.footer div#row {
    width: 100vw;
    margin-bottom: -9%!important;
    display: block;
    max-width: none;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 0!important;
}

div.container.footer div#row div#coords {
    margin-top: 0.3%; //instead of margin-top: 3%;
    padding-top: 3%;
}

.clearboth {
    clear: both;
}
```

I added a clearboth div after the 2 .col-md-5 divs. Clear: both is used to end the floating. Otherwise the `div#row` would not have the height of its children combined.

Your HTML will look like this:

```
<div id="coords">...</div>
<div class="col-md-5">...</div>
<div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-2">...</div>
<div class="clearboth"></div>
```

Comment: And the problem is resolved on 1920x1080 screens and above? And what is the meaning of : vw ?

Comment: Thats View width, the width of the users browser. You could probably use 100% aswell. And yes.

Comment: Last question : For Safari too the problem has been solved?

Comment: Didn't test that. I hate the Safari Developers toolbar haha.. But since the problem also occured in Chrome I suppose it will work.

Comment: Is there a way to test my website on the lastest Safari's version on Windows (I don't have a Mac)? Virtual machine or online? Maybe I'll need them in the future.

Comment: @JoëlGobeil At work we use Browserstack but it's rather expensive. I don't really see a different option. You could make an trial account for browserstack tho.